# How to Display the values without null values..?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to display the values without NULL values. i'm new to vc++ please anyone give the solution.

char actualKey[41];

My output :
       0F3798250D5C6C47ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
but

i want this,
   0F3798250D5C6C47

Comment: please show the code you are using to write in actualKey

Comment: The problem is that there is no terminating '\0' at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.. my code is    char actualKey[41];
 actualKey[40] = NULL;

            for(i=0;i < noOfBytesRead ;i++) 
   {
                    actualKey[j++] = map[((unsigned)(buffer[i] & 0xF0)) >> 4];
                    actualKey[j++] = map[((unsigned)(buffer[i] & 0x0F))];
            }
            printf("\nKey:%s\n",actualKey);

Comment: You should update your question with the code rather that plopping it into a comment, Karth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this first, initialize all the values to zero.

```
memset(actualKey, sizeof(actualKey), 0);
```

Comment: Or avoid the call to `memset` with `char actualKey[41] = {};`.

Comment: or `char actualKey[41] = "";`